# green screen to transparent with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg does a very good job of getting rid of a green screen, with a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=606x1080 
       -i input.mp4  
       -filter_complex 
            "[1:v]chromakey=0x70de77:0.1:0.2[ckout];
            [0:v][ckout]overlay[out]" 
       -map "[out]"  output.mp4
```

but it replaces the green screen with solid black, whereas I would like it replaced with a transparent background, alpha = 0.

I tried setting the color to `#00000000` (8 zeroes indicating a zero alpha), but that still resulted in a black background.

Strangely, when I set the color to say red, it gives a red tint to many unfiltered areas.

So I would like a transparent background, but I'm also curious what the color option is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output by MP4 defaults to the H.264 codec for the video. H.264 does not support alpha.

You can output to `.mov` with a video codec `-c:v` of `png` or `qtrle`. There are others but they have restrictions on resolution and framerate.

You can't use the overlay filter as it doesn't output to a pixel format with alpha. So, just the chromakey filter, and no color source.

Comment: Thanks. So something like this? 'ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=#00000000:s=606x1080 -i  input.mp4 -c: png  -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=0x70de77:0.1:0.2[out]" -map "[out]"  output.mov'

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "chromakey=0x70de77:0.1:0.2" -c copy -c:v png output.mov`

Comment: That indeed works -thanks! But the .mov file is a huge! 2 min of video which is 58MB as mp4 turns into 15GB of mov. And then I need to display it on the web, and it seems only webm will handle alpha channel video in a browser. And that is multiples larger. (Can't give an exact figure because I haven't got it to complete yet!).

Comment: VP8 shouldn't be multiples larger. Somewhat, yes. PNG or QTRLE will be much larger; they are intra-frame lossless codecs. QTRLE employ very basic compression. PNG is better.

Comment: Tried various permutations. keep getting "Transparency encoding with auto_alt_ref does not work" and "maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height". This was one thing I tried that gave those errors: 'ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "chromakey=0x70de77:0.1:0.2" -c copy -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M output.webm'

Comment: Ah, I see from an answer you gave elsewhere that I need to add the '-auto-alt-ref 0'  option, then i get a nice small transparent video. thanks for all your help.

Comment: What's the final command?